# How do I sync friend- shared google calendars?

Tags: iphone, mac, google-calendar

I have an iPhone, iMac, Macbook Air and a girlfriend. So far, so good.

I have multiple Google Calendars that sync perfectly to my iDevices.

The trouble is, I haven't found out yet how to sync the calendars ***my girlfriend shares with me*** to the iPhone. They do show perfectly on the Macs though.

Could anyone share the procedure if they managed this arcane spell?

Comment: See, my edit for an update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly the same set-up :)
Mac, iPhone, iPad and girlfriend. I've got a bunch of calenders, and so does my girlfriend.

In Google Calenders, hover on the agenda you want to share and hit the little arrow on the right. A new menu pops open and select "Share this agenda". Now you can invite other people to this agenda by submitting their e-mail address. And you can give them rights (read, write, read/write...)

I hope this works! If not, please let me know cause it's a delight to work with a Mac, iPhone, iPad and girlfriend. Trust me, I know ;-)

**EDIT**
To get the agenda of your girlfriend, look for the label "Other Agenda's" on the right and paste your girlfriends' e-mail there. And if your girlfriend has shared her agendas with you, they will appear on yours.

Comment: @Kheldar, I updated my answer! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with adding group calendars (i.e., calendars for Google Groups to which I had edit privileges) as well as subscribed (read-only) calendars. Checking those calendars on [this tiny "Sync Select" settings page on Google](https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect) fixed the issue for me. Why Google has this obscure, separate settings page for sync instead of consolidated these preferences into the regular Calendar settings page is beyond me.